# Is it possible to separate aluminum hydroxide?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I want to know a way to separate aluminum hydroxide into aluminum and hydroxide ions, with a chemical reaction, or another process if necessary.

I have $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ and I want to separate it into $\ce{Al}$ and $\ce{{}^{-}OH}$.

Comment: What do you mean by separate? Do you want to isolate the ions on their own or simply break apart the lattice in the solid?

Comment: There are countless possibilities in what you could have meant: 1: You're seeking homework help and asking for the net ionic reaction. 2: You're looking for an easy "home" experiment, with consideration to (1.either safety 2. or possibility 3. or economical applicability). 3: You're curious about how they perform such an "action" in industrial chemistry. 4: You want info in the field of geochemistry, looking for a possible reaction that happens in a possible mineral. etc. etc. etc. And this is only when I understand that you mean break apart the lattice. **Unclear what you're asking, really.**

Comment: I have Al(OH)₃. I want to separate the following into Al and OH-

Comment: High school student here, I immediately thought of more active metals in the activity series table. Is it possible to have the aluminum hydroxide react with a more active metal to replace the aluminum and yield elemental aluminum and the substitute metal hydroxide?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really possible to have isolated hydroxide (-OH), because it is charged.  Only neutral compounds can be isolated, not ions.